# CloudWatch Endpoint Response is same for all API Gateway routes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a simple API Gateway setup right now with three routes - `$connect, $disconnect, OnMessage`. Each of them trigger a different Lambda function.

The Lambda function is the default one:

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'), // Varies for each Lambda function
    };
    return response;
};
```

Except the `JSON.stringify` part is different for the three routes.

Right now all I'm trying to do is connect to the API Gateway's websocket URL and trigger the functions. I am able to connect to the websocket and CloudWatch also logs the three triggers correctly so I know that aspect is working.

But when I check the logs, the `Endpoint Response before Transformation` is the same for all three:
[image: CloudWatch Endpoint Response]

It should be `"Hello from Lambda"` only for `$connect`'s log.

The metrics under `Monitor` in the Lambda console reflect the functions triggering accurately but the response returned is not the right one.

How do I fix this?

Am I understanding the CloudWatch logs wrongly or is there a specific setting or setup I need to do to get accurate results?

Any pointers regarding this will be helpful.

Edit:
I changed `$connect`'s Lambda function and it turns out that the response in CloudWatch logs is not from this Lambda function. The endpoint response is just the default Lambda function.

Comment: *it turns out that the response in CloudWatch logs is not from this Lambda function*: that would've been my first guess, and it's been asked about already, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64833782/aws-lambda-keeps-returning-hello-from-lambda

Comment: I have deployed my code changes and there is no version conflict

Comment: Nevermind, I thought the API was the only thing we deploy. I didn't see that the Lambda functions also need to be deployed

Comment: Given the issue, I believe this question is a duplicate of [the one I commented earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64833782/aws-lambda-keeps-returning-hello-from-lambda), and should be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comment above pointed out, it had to do with deploying the Lambda functions.
I thought the API was the only thing we deploy but we also need to deploy the Lambda functions to get them to work properly.